# Add a nickname to a gpg key

Tags: pgp, gnupg

I want to add, additionally to my real name, my nickname (or alias or AKA) which I am better acknowledged on the web; into my public pgp key.

What's the proper way to get this done on gpg?

Comment: I don't understand why @andrew-barber has marked my question as 'on hold', I don't know so much about gpg, that's why I'm asking what is the best way to add a nickname. It's not too broad, it's just what I'm asking and shouldn't be something too long to explain.

Comment: This will be partially as the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow (your question is not about programming _at all_), have a look at the [FAQ]. On the other hand, there is no single, valid answer for this question; which will have been the reason it was finally closed as "too broad". Don't bother, but next time think twice on which site to post it.

Comment: @JensErat has my reasons pegged. I actually should have gone with the Off-Topic as not related to programming, as that's the more clear reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple choices. Which way to go for depends on your needs and preferences. A brief discussion about advantages and disadvantages of the individual ones:

- The **"usenet" style**, adding the pseudonym in quotes between the given and last name:

  ```
  John 'Random Hacker' Doe <john@example.org>
  ```

  I'd prefer this version, making it clear what the pseudonym part is and not misusing the comment field, but it might prevent some (few) from signing your key if they're strict in their naming policy.
- (Mis)using the **comment field**:

  ```
  John Doe (Random Hacker) <john@example.org>
  ```

  Probably with less problems while getting signatures for your key, but the [use of the comment field is often regarded critical](https://www.debian-administration.org/users/dkg/weblog/97).
- Adding a **separate user ID**:

  ```
  John Doe <john@example.org>
  Random Hacker <hacker@example.net>
  ```

  Especially a good idea when  having a separate mail address for the nick name. You probably will not get signatures on that user ID. If you're going for this way, consider putting the pseudonym in quotes anyway and maybe even create a separate key for it.

Comment: Is there an unattended way of generating keys with multiple UIDs?